# Set Jenkins jnlp agent to use WebSocket programmatically with API

Tags: java, rest, jenkins, continuous-integration

I have a jenkins master and worker setup in AWS. I want the worker to auto-connect to the master.  I can define a new node with an API request. However because of the network in cannot use TCP on port 50000 as Jenkins likes to. So the `java -jar agent.jar...` command fails on the handshake. I cannot easily get around this network problem quickly for organization reasons.

There is however an option to use a websocket for jnlp. If I go into the Jenkins UI and the created node and turn this option on, I can then successfully connect via websocket.

My question, is how do I set a jnlp node to websocket with the API before I execute the agent.jar?

Comment: What kind of API are you using -- the REST API or the CLI/ssh API?

Comment: This is the REST api

Comment: I know this is an old quesiton, but anyway, add in the jnlp file `<argument>-webSocket</argument><argument>` you'll need to dwnload the jnlp file locally and edit it, then start the agent by using the local file. `java -jar /opt/sysmon/jenkins/agent.jar -jnlpUrl file:/opt/jenkins/jenkins-agent.jnlp -workDir /opt/somedir` not that this option does not want the `-secret` option. All of this can be scripted, for easy deployment, obviously.